# Xamarin Forms Android app is not working through Microsoft Defender/Intune split tunnel vpn

Tags: xamarin, vpn, tunnel, intune

The app gets an error that the host is unknown while connecting to a url that the split tunnel should consider as internal.

I use httpClient with Android implementation with default (Native TLS 1.2+) SSL/TLS implementation.

I believe that the problem is not in the vpn configuration because a prototype app using the same code to make the POST works even using the same package name of the app that doesn't.

The target Framework is Android 13.
The prototype is very small and the app is a very large one, with hundreds of libraries.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.6.5.

I tried making the POST while opening the main page and even so, it fails.

I would like to know where to get a log of which problem is happening, to help me identify which code/library is causing the incompatibility.

The same app works fine outside vpn and using GlobalProtect vpn.

These are the nugets I'm using:

```
  <PackageReference Include="Plugin.BLE">
      <Version>2.1.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http">
      <Version>4.3.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.DataBinding.ViewBinding" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout.Solver" Version="2.0.4.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Acr.UserDialogs">
      <Version>7.0.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="CarouselView.FormsPlugin">
      <Version>6.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Honeywell.BarcodeReader">
      <Version>1.35.0.17</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter">
      <Version>5.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics">
      <Version>5.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes">
      <Version>5.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="morelinq">
      <Version>3.4.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="NCalcSync">
      <Version>3.6.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>13.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Connectivity">
      <Version>1.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.CurrentActivity">
      <Version>2.1.0.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.LocalNotification">
      <Version>10.1.5</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Permissions">
      <Version>6.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="PropertyChanged.Fody">
      <Version>4.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Rg.Plugins.Popup">
      <Version>2.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog">
      <Version>2.12.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Compact">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Async">
      <Version>1.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File">
      <Version>5.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching">
      <Version>3.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq">
      <Version>5.2.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Xamarin">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Svg">
      <Version>1.60.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Splat">
      <Version>14.6.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl">
      <Version>1.8.116</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SQLiteNetExtensions">
      <Version>2.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.Buttons">
      <Version>21.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfCarousel">
      <Version>21.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfDataGrid">
      <Version>21.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfImageEditor">
      <Version>21.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfListView">
      <Version>21.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfNavigationDrawer">
      <Version>21.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPdfViewer">
      <Version>21.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPopupLayout">
      <Version>21.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPullToRefresh">
      <Version>21.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity">
      <Version>3.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Geolocator">
      <Version>4.5.0.6</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media">
      <Version>6.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugins.DownloadManager">
      <Version>1.4.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugins.Messaging">
      <Version>5.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat">
      <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation">
      <Version>1.6.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat">
      <Version>1.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources">
      <Version>1.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection">
      <Version>1.2.0.8</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core">
      <Version>1.10.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.CursorAdapter">
      <Version>1.0.0.18</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView">
      <Version>1.1.0.17</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.DocumentFile">
      <Version>1.0.1.18</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout">
      <Version>1.2.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.ExifInterface">
      <Version>1.3.6.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment">
      <Version>1.5.7.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Interpolator">
      <Version>1.0.0.18</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Leanback">
      <Version>1.0.0.20</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Extensions">
      <Version>2.2.0.18</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.Ktx">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Process">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime.Ktx">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Service">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.Ktx">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModelSavedState">
      <Version>2.6.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter">
      <Version>1.4.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration">
      <Version>1.0.10</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Auth">
      <Version>1.7.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Build.Download">
      <Version>0.11.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.CommunityToolkit">
      <Version>2.0.6</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup">
      <Version>2.0.6</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms">
      <Version>3.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.DocumentReader.Api.Android">
      <Version>5.6.4832</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.DocumentReader.Common.Android">
      <Version>5.7.825</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.DocumentReader.Core.OcrAndMRZ.Android">
      <Version>5.8.5727</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Dropbox.Api">
      <Version>4.5.3.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials">
      <Version>1.8.0-preview1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms">
      <Version>2.4.11.982</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Common">
      <Version>120.3.2.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Iid">
      <Version>121.1.0.9</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging">
      <Version>123.1.2.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms">
      <Version>5.0.0.2599-pre1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Maps">
      <Version>5.0.0.2599-pre1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="XLabs.Forms">
      <Version>2.3.0-pre02</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile">
      <Version>2.4.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms">
      <Version>2.4.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

The vpn was supposed to allow the access to the internal server but it fails.

Comment: Removing sharedUserId from AndroidManifest.xml solved the problem.